# Error while running python dataflow job:

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to process an input text file using its first character using GCP Dataflow Python. If the first character of an entry is 'A', I want to store the file in A.txt and so on. Similarly, I have a number associated with each character. I have stored two hashmaps for this. The following is my code:

```
splitHashMap={'A':1,'F':4, 'J':4, 'Z':4, 'G':10, 'I':11};
fileHashMap= {'A':'A.txt','B':'B.txt','F':'F.txt','J':'J.txt','Z':'Z.txt','G':'G.txt','I':'I.txt'};
def to_table_row(x):
  firstChar=x[0][0];
  global splitHashMap
  global fileHashMap
  print splitHashMap[firstChar];
  x | WriteToText(fileHashMap[firstChar]);
  return {firstChar}
```

The error is with the WriteToText function and is as follows:

```
PTransform Create: Refusing to treat string as an iterable. (string=u'AIGLM0012016-02-180000000112016-02-18-12.00.00.123456GB CARMB00132') [while running 'ToTableRows']
```

Could someone please help me resolve this issue?

EDIT: The remainder of the code containing the pipeline is as follows:

```
arser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--input',
                  dest='input',
                  default='gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt',
                  help='Input file to process.')
parser.add_argument('--output',
                  dest='output',
                  help='Output file to write results to.')
known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(None)
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)


lines = p | 'read' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input)


lines | 'ToTableRows' >> beam.Map(to_table_row);

result = p.run()
```

I request you to help me resolve the issue now. The command I use to tun the python file is:

```
python File_parse.py ---input temp.txt
```

Temp.txt is as follows:

```
Aasadasd asdasd adsad af
Jdsad asdasd asd as
A asdd ad agfsfg sfg 
Z afsdfrew320pjpoji
Idadfsd w8480ujfds
```

The desired output is that all the files starting with 'A' go to "A.txt", 'B' go to "B.txt" and so on. It would be great if you wrote the code in your response.

Comment: Can you share your whole pipeline code? You can't pass strings into transforms the way you are trying to. If you share your whole pipeline, we'll help you figure out how to write the functionality you need.

Comment: @Pablo: I have added the entire pipeline. You can take a look

Comment: I've answered your question. I encourage you to review the etiquette of StackOverflow, as you infringed a few things with your question. Also, if the question is helpful, you may select it as having been such.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `WriteToText` is not appropriate. You can't pass a string to a PTransform. Instead, you need to pass PCollections into PTransforms. In the following code, you can create separate PCollections for each case of a first character, and pass that

What you can do in this case is something like this:

```
file_hash_map= {'A':'A.txt','B':'B.txt','F':'F.txt',
                'J':'J.txt','Z':'Z.txt','G':'G.txt','I':'I.txt'}
existing_chars = file_hash_map.keys()

class ToTableRowDoFn(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    first_char = element[0][0]
    if first_char in file_hash_map:
      yield pvalue.TaggedOutput(first_char, element)
    else:
      # When the first char of the word is not from the allowed
      # characters, we just send it to the main output.
      yield element 

lines = p | 'read' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input)

multiple_outputs = (
    lines | 
    'ToTableRows' >> beam.ParDo(ToTableRowDoFn())
                           .with_outputs(*existing_chars, main='main'));

for pcollection_name in existing_chars:
  char_pcollection = getattr(multiple_outputs, pcollection_name)
  char_pcollection | WriteToFile(file_hash_map[pcollection_name])
```

The crux of this code is on the `for` loop, where we iterate over each one of the output PCollections, and write their contents individually to a different file.